# How we come up with: $\mathcal{w}^T\mathcal{w} = \sum_{i,j} y^{(i)}y^{(j)} \alpha_{j}\alpha_{j} (\mathbf{x}^{(i)})^T {\mathbf{x}^{(i)}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

The primal optimization problem for finding the optimal margin classifier is:

\begin{align}
\arg\min_{\mathbf{w}}\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{w}\|^2_2 \\
\text{subject to } \quad y^{(i)}(\mathbf{w^T}\mathbf{x^{(i)}}+\mathbf{b}) \ge 1
\end{align}

The Lagrangian for this optimization problem is:

$\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{w},\mathbf{b},a) = \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{w}\|^2_2 - \sum_{i}\alpha _i[y^{(i)}(\mathbf{w^T}\mathbf{x^{(i)}} + \mathbf{b})-1]$. Taking $\nabla _{\mathbf{w}}\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{w},\mathbf{b},a)=0$, we have $\mathcal{w} = \sum_i \alpha_i y^{(i)}\mathcal{x^{(i)}}$.

Based on that we have: $\mathcal{w^Tw} = \big[ \sum_i \alpha_i y^{(i)}\mathcal{x^{(i)}} \big]^T \big[ \sum_i \alpha_i y^{(i)}\mathcal{x^{(i)}} \big]$.

How we come up with this form: $\mathcal{w^Tw} = \sum_{i,j} y^{(i)}y^{(j)} \alpha_{j}\alpha_{j} (\mathbf{x}^{(i)})^T {\mathbf{x}^{(j)}}$ ?. In other words which algebric rules where aplied to have this result?

Thank you!

Comment: I have think you have typo in the last expression, it should be $(x^{i})^T x^{j}$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

$\big( \sum_j \alpha_j y^{(j)}\mathcal{x^{(j)}} \big)^T \big( \sum_i \alpha_i y^{(i)}\mathcal{x^{(i)}} \big) = \big( \sum_j (\alpha_j y^{(j)}\mathcal{x^{(j)}} )^T\big) \big( \sum_i \alpha_i y^{(i)}\mathcal{x^{(i)}} \big)$,

because $(a+b)^T = a^T+b^T$, then since $\alpha_i$ and $y_i$ are scalar, $(\alpha_j y^{(j)}\mathcal{x^{(j)}} )^T = \alpha_j y^{(j)}\mathcal{x^{(j)}}^T$ and thus

$\big( \sum_j (\alpha_j y^{(j)}\mathcal{x^{(j)}} )^T\big) \big( \sum_i \alpha_i y^{(i)}\mathcal{x^{(i)}} \big) =  \sum_j \alpha_j y^{(j)}\mathcal{x^{(j)}} ^T \big( \sum_i \alpha_i y^{(i)}\mathcal{x^{(i)}} \big) = \sum_j \sum_i \alpha_j y^{(j)}\mathcal{x^{(j)}} ^T  \alpha_i y^{(i)}\mathcal{x^{(i)}} = \sum_{i,j} \alpha_j y^{(j)}\mathcal{x^{(j)}} ^T  \alpha_i y^{(i)}\mathcal{x^{(i)}} = \sum_{i,j} \alpha_j\alpha_i y^{(j)} y^{(i)}\mathcal{x^{(j)}} ^T  \mathcal{x^{(i)}}$

Comment: Ok thanks, but which is the intuitive explanation of using different superscipts in the sums $\big( \sum_j \alpha_j y^{(j)}\mathcal{x^{(j)}} \big)^T \big( \sum_i \alpha_i y^{(i)}\mathcal{x^{(i)}} \big)$ and not the same like (both sums with $i$) in my post. This was my question from the begining. Thanks again!

Comment: You can use the same indeces for the sum, but that will get you in trouble, when you are trying the combine them into one sum. The summation does not change whether you choose $k$, $m$ or $j$ as a letter, you can change them always. Therefore changing one of the sums to a different index is not a problem and makes it more convenient to model the combination of both sums.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I recognize the fact that it is convinient to work with sums of different indexes but which is the mathematical support of this fact?

Comment: Are you asking for the proof, why both products (one using two indices and the other using the same index) are the same, or why it is ok to swap the index by another letter in a general sum? Sorry, I am not sure, I understand correctly your question.

Comment: If you accept, that you can swap the index of a sum by a different letter, then you see both products (same or different indeces) are the same. Or are you asking, how you would perform the product if you insist on using the same index in the sums?

Comment: I was refered in $\big( \sum_j \alpha_j y^{(j)}\mathcal{x^{(j)}} \big)^T \big( \sum_i \alpha_i y^{(i)}\mathcal{x^{(i)}} \big)$. You mentioned that it is convinient to use different indexes in the sums. Which is the mathematical-analytical reason for this. The product $w^Tw$ implies this: $\big( \sum_j \alpha_j y^{(j)}\mathcal{x^{(j)}} \big)^T \big( \sum_j \alpha_i y^{(j)}\mathcal{x^{(j)}} \big)$. I hope now that I am more clear. Thanks again.

Comment: If an analytical explanation does not exist, how the product can be performed using the same index in the sums? Can you give the analysis on this? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I see. You mean, that because $w = \sum_i \alpha_i y^i x^i$ then, $w^Tw$ has to have the same index $i$ in both sums as well, right?

Comment: Keep in mind, that $i$ as variable is not a real part of the expression of $w$, it is just an auxiliary variable to make the computation of $w$ clear. $w = \sum_k \alpha_k y^k x^k = \sum_l \alpha_l y^l x^l = \sum_i \alpha_i y^i x^i$ are all the same, that's why it is perfectly fine that $w^T w= (\sum_i \alpha_i y^i x^i )( \sum_i \alpha_i y^i x^i) = (\sum_j \alpha_j y^j x^j )( \sum_i \alpha_i y^i x^i)$.

Comment: If you are still not convinced, you can just use the formal definition of the sum from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation to expand every factor of the product into sums $(a_0+a_1 + ... + a_n)(b_0 + b_1 + .. b_n)$ multiply that out (or mentally) and notice that in order to describe the resulting summation which you need to perform, you will need to introduce a double summation with two different indices i.e. $i$,$j$.